# Is there a way with conan to export an empty directory?

Tags: c++, conan

Considering a folder (called parent_folder) containing an empty folder (called empty_son_folder) and another one that is not empty (called not_empty_son_folder) and the following exports_sources method:

```
exports_sources = ["parent_folder*"]
```

Only not_empty_son_folder is exported.

Is there a way with conan to force to copy an empty folder in export source method?

Comment: Would it be an option to just make it non-empty? E.g. put a dummy.txt there.

Comment: No, it is not possible. Conan operates like Git, and uses only files, not folders. Exporting empty folders doesn't make sense. What is your use case? If you need the folders later in your recipe, you can do a ``mkdir("myfolder")`` when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Yumnosch said it is possible to add a dummy file to force conan to include this folder or create this folder later in the receipe (@drodri's solution).

If the need is to have files generated by some test programs, both solutions work.

It is also possible to create such a folder directly in the test program that needs it.